# Запись данных в указатель

Tags: c#

Переписываю функции проигрывания *bik* видео на *C#*.
Имеется такая функция на *Delphi*:

```
BinkCopyToBuffer : function(bink: HBink; destBuf: pointer; Pitch, Height, Xoffset, Yoffset, Flags: Longword): Longword; stdcall;
```

И на *C++*:

```
RADEXPFUNC S32  RADEXPLINK BinkCopyToBuffer(HBINK bnk,void* dest,S32 destpitch,U32 destheight,U32 destx,U32 desty,U32 flags);
```

На *C#* я представляю её так:

```
public static extern uint BinkCopyToBuffer(TBink bink, IntPtr dest, uint Pitch, uint Height, uint Xoffset, uint Yoffset, BinkSurface flag);
```

Вызываю так:

```
IntPtr bits = new IntPtr();
BinkCopyToBuffer(binkS, bits, binkS.Width * 4, binkS.Height, 0, 0, BinkSurface.BINKSURFACE32);
```

Программа вылетает на этой функции с ошибкой 0xC0000005:

> Потоком была предпринята попытка прочитать или записать данные на виртуальный адрес, к которому он не имеет соответствующего доступа.

Как позволить функции записать данные в указатель `bits`?

Comment: `IntPtr dest` -> `byte[] dest`. И передавайте в функцию массив необходимого размера.

Comment: Хм. А что, по-вашему, делает строчка `IntPtr bits = new IntPtr();`?

Comment: PetSerAl, вылетает с ошибкой 0xC0000005

Comment: Попробуйте так: `IntPtr bits = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(размер_в_байтах)`, а потом передавайте в функцию свои `bits`

Answer (score 1):

`IntPtr` - это просто целое число, конструкция `new IntPtr()` вернет ноль. По нулевому адресу ничего записать, разумеется, нельзя.

Выделить кусок памяти можно через [`Marshal.AllocHGlobal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s69bkh17(v=vs.110).aspx) или через [`Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.alloccotaskmem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Или же можно передавать массив байт. В таком случае понадобится подсказать среде выполнения, что данный массив байт надо передавать как указатель на первый элемент:

```
 public static extern uint BinkCopyToBuffer(TBink bink, 
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] dest,
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`new IntPtr();` - создание нового указателя, насколько я понимаю. Указатель - просто адрес, чтобы что-то куда-то записать вам нужно выделить память.

Comment: По тому указателю функция записывает массив байтов. Размер массива известен. Как выделить память и по указателю записать сие чудо?

Comment: Если бы у вас был более другой язык, я бы написал так:
void* dstPtr = malloc(SIZE);
BinkCopyToBuffer(binkS, dstPtr, ...). Но ваш язык я не использую и не знаю.

Comment: Это даже не указатель, `IntPtr` — это `int` такой разрядности, что в принципе может содержать указатель.

Comment: @VladD всюду обман :-(